# How to build pygkt 2.18

Tags: pygtk

The gtk version of my linux PC  is 2.18.
But I can't find corresponding pytgtk from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/

Answer (score 0):

The GTK library is one thing, the PyGTK interface to that library is another thing.

The GTK lib is living http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php and it's usually just enough to compile it in a folder like ./usr/GTK and add that folder to your path.

The PyGTK lives in http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php but I prefer to install it from synaptic : `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2`

There is no need to have the pyGTK of the same version number as the GTK.